# CakePHP 3 : login using model other than User

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.x

I am working on a CakePHP 3 project.
This project contains multiple Admins and thus a separate table `admins`.

I have to use `admins` model to login to the site but, it is not working.

I tried configuring authenticate as given [here](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers/components/authentication.html#configuring-authentication-handlers).

This is my `AppController.php`

```
<?php
namespace App\Controller;

use Cake\Controller\Controller;
use Cake\Event\Event;


class AppController extends Controller
{

    /**
     * Initialization hook method.
     *
     * Use this method to add common initialization code like loading components.
     *
     * e.g. `$this->loadComponent('Security');`
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function initialize()
    {
        parent::initialize();

        $this->loadComponent('RequestHandler');
        $this->loadComponent('Flash');
        $this->loadComponent('Auth', [
          'authenticate' => [
            'Form' => [
              'fields' => [
                'username' => 'username',
                'password' => 'password'
              ]
            ]
          ],
          'loginAction' => [
            'controller' => 'Admins',
            'action' => 'login'
          ],
          'loginRedirect' => [
            'controller' => 'ServiceRequests',
            'action' => 'index'
          ],
          'logoutRedirect' => [
            'controller' => 'Admins',
            'action' => 'login'
          ]
        ]);
        $this->Auth->config('authenticate', [
          AuthComponent::ALL => ['userModel' => 'Admin'],
          'Basic',
          'Form'
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * Before render callback.
     *
     * @param \Cake\Event\Event $event The beforeRender event.
     * @return void
     */
    public function beforeRender(Event $event)
    {
        if (!array_key_exists('_serialize', $this->viewVars) &&
            in_array($this->response->type(), ['application/json', 'application/xml'])
        ) {
            $this->set('_serialize', true);
        }
    }
}
```

But this is giving `Fatal` error as

```
Error: Class 'App\Controller\AuthComponent' not found 
File /var/www/html/flickfix.com/public_html/admin2/src/Controller/AppController.php 
Line: 69
```

Removing `$this->Auth->config` gives error as

```
Error: Call to undefined method Cake\Controller\Component\AuthComponent::identity() 
File /var/www/html/flickfix.com/public_html/admin2/src/Controller/AdminsController.php 
Line: 118
```

Login action in `AdminsController.php`

```
  public function login() {
        if($this->request->is('post')) {
          $user = $this->Auth->identity();
          if ($user) {
            $this->Auth->setUser($user);
            return $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirectUrl());
          }
          $this->Flash->error('Your username or password is incorrect.');
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely the error

```
Error: Class 'App\Controller\AuthComponent' not found
```

is caused by line

```
AuthComponent::ALL => ['userModel' => 'Admin']
```

in your code.

Since you don't have a

```
use Cake\Controller\Component\AuthComponent;
```

statement at top of your file, PHP is trying to find AuthComponent in current namespace.

Comment: I added `use Cake\Controller\Component\AuthComponent;` to `AppController.php` and now it is giving error as `Error: Call to undefined method Cake\Controller\Component\AuthComponent::identity() ` (2nd error in question)

Comment: That's strange, AuthComponent does have a identify() method. Maybe your cake core is messed up. You can try emptying your "vendor" folder and running `composer update` to get fresh copies of libs.

Comment: Any idea about how to do this with CakePHP4, since AuthComponent is deprecated?